# Passing Data from Delphi Client to / from Web Service

Tags: web-services, delphi

If I create a web  service in Delphi XE as CGI executable, what's the best way for it to return data to a client? Say the server uses ADO to access SQL server and the data is stored in a TADODataSet component - what's the best way to get it back to the client through a web service call? Do I need to convert it to XML and return it as a string and have the client recreate it?

Comment: Most web services try to be language and platform agnostic, and use a data representation format which is not bound to specific components. Of course you could use binary serialization of the original ADO component content for performance reasons, but it it is less flexible. Regarding XML: JSON is very popular too.

Answer (score 1):

With the DataSnap framework it is possible to send dataset between server and client(s).

See more here : [can-delphi-2009-build-web-service-that-returns-a-dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509404/can-delphi-2009-build-web-service-that-returns-a-dataset)